# How to set different width for cells in recyclerview in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

In my recyclerview I get address as one of the data. If the address length >  50dp (say) then I want to cut it to 2 lines(for that cell) and this increases the height of this cell. However I would like to make all the cells match this new height (to keep it uniform).

Please let me know how to achieve this. Is there anything I could tweak below?

```
public class CustomerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < CustomerAdapter.CustomerViewHolder > {  
    List < Customer > mCustomerList;  
    public CustomerAdapter(List < Customer > customerList) {  
        this.mCustomerList = customerList;  
    }  
    @Override  
    public CustomerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {  
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_customer, parent, false);  
        return new CustomerViewHolder(view);  
    }  
    @Override  
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomerViewHolder holder, int position) {  
        Customer customer = mCustomerList.get(position);  
        holder.tvName.setText(customer.mCustomerName);  
        holder.tvAddress.setText(customer.mCustomerAddress);  
    }  
    @Override  
    public int getItemCount() {  
        return mCustomerList.size();  
    }  
    public class CustomerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {  
        TextView tvName, tvAddress;  
        public CustomerViewHolder(View itemView) {  
            super(itemView);  
            this.tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);  
            this.tvAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_address);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to make your text fields always 2 lines in height, that way the cells will be uniform.

If you only want to use 2 lines if at least 1 cell requires 2 lines, then you will need to measure how many lines each text field will require and determine if there is at least 1 that requires 2 lines, and then set all of them to 2 lines, otherwise set them to 1 line.

You can use [StaticLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout) to measure the number of lines the text will require before it is rendered.